# Access to attribute in directive

Tags: angular, binding, angular2-directives

I have been trying to access the href value from a directive bind, but without any luck.

```
<a class="u-link-default" [attr.href]="tosUrl">Terms</a>
```

**The directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'a'
})
export class ExternalLinkDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() href: string;
  @HostBinding('rel') rel: string;
  @HostBinding('target') target: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.href); // no value
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.href); // no value
  }
}
```

PD: `<a class="u-link-default" href="https://fakedomain.com">Terms</a>` works, I already checked "tosUrl" is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Change `[attr.href]="tosUrl"` to `[href]="tosUrl"`

Comment: I did this <a class="u-link-default" [attr.href]="tosUrl" [href]="tosUrl">Terms <a/>because I didn't want to loose the attribute binding. I know is not so elegant but it works though, I wonder if there is possible to access de attr. directive in a better way.

Comment: Yeah, you can access the attribute in the directive. You have access to the native element, simply inject it in the contructor: constructor(private element: ElementRef){}